# ie10 system phone colors in css

Tags: windows-phone-8

According to the CSS spec http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#system-colors there are some available predefined system colors.

It appears that:

- Background -> Maps to the PhoneBackgroundBrush
- Highlight -> Maps to the PhoneAccentBrush

I am looking for the css value equivalent to PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush. (If there's any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported at present time. To confirm this I specially contacted MS guys presented this feature on BUILD conference - https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-015

Comment: That's too bad. Thank you nevertheless!